# Implementation of External JS Code in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following JS code for counting score in a survey that I would like to implement in to HTML:

```
function displayScore() 
{
    var score = $('<p>',{id: 'question'});
    var points = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) 
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < questions[i].choices.length; j++)
        {
            if (selections[i] === j) 
            {
                points += questions[i].choiceValues[j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to have a  for counting score throughout the survey. My current HTML code looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form Project</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='privacy toolkit.css'/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open Sans"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='container'>
        <div id='title'>
            <h1>The Privacy Toolkit</h1>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div id='quiz'></div>
        <div class='button' id='next'><a href='#'>Next</a></div>
        <div class='button' id='prev'><a href='#'>Prev</a></div>
        <div class='button' id='start'> <a href='#'>Start Over</a></div>
        <!-- <button class='' id='next'>Next</a></button>
        <button class='' id='prev'>Prev</a></button>
        <button class='' id='start'> Start Over</a></button> -->
    </div>
    <script type='text/javascript' 
            src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'>
    </script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='privacy toolkit.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I believe to do this, there should be a  inside the container div running the JS code.

Comment: What is the counter counting?  The current user's score? Or the total of all the submitted forms? Furthermore, is this a single-page app?  Are there going to be page refreshes/reloads/redirects for different parts of the survey?  Also, what are your limitations: jQuery? VanillaJS? React?

Comment: The counter is counting the cumulative score as the user answers questions in a form. This is a single page app. My limitations are jQuery

Comment: Was my answer helpful? Can you close out the question?

Comment: Did this help at all? Haha

Comment: Hey @Tamb, this was very useful, sorry I didn't respond. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so let's say you're counting two types of scores:
Chocolate and Vanilla

The counter HTML:

```
<h2>Chocolate</h2>
<div class="js-counter chocolate">
    <span class="js-counter__number"></span>
</div>

<h2>Vanilla</h2>
<div class="js-counter vanilla">
    <span class="js-counter__number"></span>
</div>
```

The form HTML:

```
<form>
   <input type="checkbox" name="vanilla" value="vanilla" data-count="vanilla" data-countby="1"/>
   <input type="checkbox" name="chocolate" value="chocolate" data-count="chocolate" data-countby="1"/>
</form>
```

Create a class for the counter:

```
    var Counter = function(startingCount, $el, $counterTrigger){
       this.count = startingCount || 0;//defaults to 0
       this.$rootEl = $el;
       this.$counterTrigger = $counterTrigger;
       this.$counterText = this.$rootEl.find('.js-counter__number');
       this.setInitial();
       this.bindEvents();

    }
    //add an ADD method to this class
    Counter.prototype.add = function(countBy){
       this.count = this.count + parseInt(countBy);//add to the count property
       this.$counterText.text(this.count);

    }
   //set the initial value to the DOM
    Counter.prototype.setInitial = function(){
      this.$counterText.text(this.count);
    }
    //bind the USER EVENTS
    Counter.prototype.bindEvents = function(){
        var that = this;

        this.$counterTrigger.on('change', function(){
            if(this.checked){
                that.add(that.$counterTrigger.attr('data-countBy'));
            }
        });
    }
```

when the page is ready, instantiate the classes

```
$(function(){
    var counters = [];

    counters.push( new Counter(0,$('.js-counter.chocolate'),$('[data-count="chocolate"]')) );
    counters.push( new Counter(0,$('.js-counter.vanilla'),$('[data-count="vanilla"]')) );

});
```

This is not perfect. It's also making a few assumptions about what you're counting, what's triggering the count, etc.

But the basic idea is you want to keep track of something. It may be many things, so that's why it's a class.

When you instantiate the class, you can pass in all of your parameters.  This is where I got sloppy.  There are much more efficient and cleaner ways to do this.  But the idea is to create an initial value for each counter. Store the DOM elements as properties.

Then I create the counter text with setInitial();

And on change to the input, do whatever checks you need, then add whatever amount you need to the counter count.  Then simple update the view with the counter count.  But it's a lot easier this way to store a DOM element and update the text only.  That way the references to those elements are stored in memory "cached" and you don't need to query them later.  I would advice reading up on ES5 AND ES6 classes.  This will help out a ton.

REMEMBER: Querying and Updating DOM elements is expensive.  Do as little of this as you can and you'll be good.

lmk if you have questions

here's a plunk   https://plnkr.co/edit/1XXlsfMy01KR6ascFciG?p=preview